# Calculate median and quartile in C without sorting the array

Tags: c, median

Here's a piece of working code wrote in C to calculate the median without putting all values in an array and sorting them. It reads values from a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double find_min(FILE *, double, double);
double find_max(FILE *, double, double);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int CLASSES = 2; // number of parts we create when splitting the set every single pass
    double GRANULE = 0.001; // minimum precision desired, should be >=1 if numbers are integers

    FILE * file_p; // data file
    file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    int i, valueIndex1, valueIndex2, N;
    // i is the index used in the for loops
    // valueIndex1 is the 1st token we read from each line of the data file
    // valueIndex2 is the 1st token we read from each line of the data file, in a different read
    // N is the number of values in the initial set, we'll check if it's even or odd

    double value;
    // value is the 2nd token we read from each line of the data file, it's an observation

    int count[CLASSES];
    // count[n] is the number of elements in the nth part we create during a single pass

    double min, max, delta;
    // min is the minimum (inclusive) of the elements considered in the current pass
    // max is the maximum (exclusive) of the elements considered in the current pass
    // delta is the difference between the minimum and maximum values of every single part created during the current pass

    double lowerBounds[CLASSES], upperBounds[CLASSES];
    // lowerBounds[n] is the minimum value (inclusive) that can be in the nth part created during a pass
    // upperBounds[n] is the maximum value (exclusive) that can be in the nth part created during a pass

    int sum, tmpsum, limit;
    sum = tmpsum = 0;
    // sum is the number of elements in the parts before the ones we just create each pass
    // tmpsum is the number of elements in the parts before the one we are considering during the pass
    // limit is the number of elements the median should be greater than

    int index_median;
    // index_median is the number of the class containing the median element

    short beyondPrecision; // beyondPrecision is raised to 1 if we are creating classes with a range < GRANULE

    double median;
    // median is where we store the value of the median before returning it


    // find minimum and maximum values of the whole set

    fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex1, &min);

    max = min;

    while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex1, &value) != EOF) {

        if (value < min)
            min = value;

        if (value > max)
            max = value;

    }

    N = ++valueIndex1;
    // The number of values is calculated as the last of indexes found + 1
    // It's equivalent to the number of lines in the file

    max++; // make exclusive

    // check if N is even or odd
    if (N % 2)
        limit = N / 2 + 1;
    else
        limit = N / 2;

    delta = (max - min) / (CLASSES);

    // define the borders of the initial frequency classes

    for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {

        lowerBounds[i] = min + i*delta;
        upperBounds[i] = min + (i + 1) * delta;
        count[i] = 0;

    }

    // find the class (part) the median is in
    // we keep dividing in smaller classes until we meet one of the 2 exit conditions

    while (1) {

        fclose(file_p);
        file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        // fill the frequency classes
        // during the first pass they are the initial classes, then they will be parts of the chosen part

        while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex2, &value) != EOF) {

            for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; i++) {

                if (value >= lowerBounds[i] && value < upperBounds[i])
                    count[i]++;

            }

        }

        // select the class containing the median. It will be the first one with (#elements + #elements of classes on its left) > N/2

        for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {

            tmpsum += count[i];

            if (tmpsum > limit) {

                index_median = i;
                break;

            }

            sum += count[i];

        }

        min = lowerBounds[index_median];
        max = upperBounds[index_median];

        // if the number of elements on the left is exactly N/2, then we are done (exit condition satisfied)
        // in that case, the median is calculated outside this cycle as the maximum element of the class (part) numbered index_median - 1

        if (sum == limit)
            break;

        // if the median appears many times in the set, then we need a way to figure it out before we create classes that are too small,
        // so we exit after reaching a certain fixed precision

        if (max - min < GRANULE) {

            beyondPrecision = 1;
            index_median++;
            break;

        }

        // set the borders of the new frequency classes (for next pass)
        // they are created by dividing the class containing the median

        delta = (max - min) / (CLASSES);

        for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {

            lowerBounds[i] = min + i*delta;
            upperBounds[i] = min + (i + 1) * delta;
            count[i] = 0;

        }

        tmpsum = sum;

    }

    // now we now which class the median is in and we need to extract it
    // we distinguish the 2 cases of having an ever or an odd number of observations (N)

    fclose(file_p);
    file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");


    if (N % 2 || beyondPrecision) { // N is odd or the median value appears more than one time
        median = find_max(file_p, lowerBounds[index_median - 1], upperBounds[index_median - 1]);
    } else { // N is even
        double a, b;
        // a is the maximum value in the left part, where the 1st value necessary to calculate the median
        // b is the minimum value in the right part, where the 2nd value necessary to calculate the median

        a = find_max(file_p, lowerBounds[index_median - 1], upperBounds[index_median - 1]);

        fclose(file_p);
        file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        b = find_min(file_p, lowerBounds[index_median], upperBounds[index_median]);

        median = (a + b) / 2;

    }

    fclose(file_p);

    printf("Our median is %f\n", median);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

double find_min(FILE * file_p, double lowerBound, double upperBound) {

    double value, min;
    int valueIndex;

    min = upperBound;

    while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex, &value) != EOF) {

        if (value >= lowerBound && value < upperBound && value < min)
            min = value;

    }

    return min;

}

double find_max(FILE * file_p, double lowerBound, double upperBound) {

    double value, max;
    int valueIndex;

    max = lowerBound;

    while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex, &value) != EOF) {

        if (value >= lowerBound && value < upperBound && value > max)
            max = value;

    }

    return max;

}
```

And here is the code to calculate the quartile, based on the same principle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double find_min(FILE *, double, double);
double find_max(FILE *, double, double);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int CLASSES = 2; // number of parts we create when splitting the set every single pass
    double GRANULE = 0.001; // minimum precision desired, should be >=1 if numbers are integers
    double MEDIAN = 34.2275;

    FILE * file_p; // data file
    file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    int i, valueIndex1, valueIndex2, N = 0;
    // i is the index used in the for loops
    // valueIndex1 is the 1st token we read from each line of the data file
    // valueIndex2 is the 1st token we read from each line of the data file, in a different read
    // N is the number of values in the initial set, we'll check if it's even or odd

    double value;
    // value is the 2nd token we read from each line of the data file, it's an observation

    int count[CLASSES];
    // count[n] is the number of elements in the nth part we create during a single pass

    double min, max, delta;
    // min is the minimum (inclusive) of the elements considered in the current pass
    // max is the maximum (exclusive) of the elements considered in the current pass
    // delta is the difference between the minimum and maximum values of every single part created during the current pass

    double lowerBounds[CLASSES], upperBounds[CLASSES];
    // lowerBounds[n] is the minimum value (inclusive) that can be in the nth part created during a pass
    // upperBounds[n] is the maximum value (exclusive) that can be in the nth part created during a pass

    int sum, tmpsum, limit;
    sum = tmpsum = 0;
    // sum is the number of elements in the parts before the ones we just create each pass
    // tmpsum is the number of elements in the parts before the one we are considering during the pass
    // limit is the number of elements the quartile should be greater than

    int index_quartile;
    // index_quartile is the number of the class containing the quartile element

    short beyondPrecision; // beyondPrecision is raised to 1 if we are creating classes with a range < GRANULE

    double quartile;
    // quartile is where we store the value of the quartile before returning it


    // find minimum and maximum values of the whole set

    while (N == 0) {
        fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex1, &value);

        if (value < MEDIAN) {

            min = value;
            max = min;
            N++; // N is now set as a counter

        }
    }

    while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex1, &value) != EOF) {

        if (value < MEDIAN) {

            if (value < min)
                min = value;

            if (value > max)
                max = value;

            N++;
        }

    }

    max++; // make exclusive

    // check if N is even or odd
    if (N % 2)
        limit = N / 2 + 1;
    else
        limit = N / 2;

    delta = (max - min) / (CLASSES);

    // define the borders of the initial frequency classes

    for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {

        lowerBounds[i] = min + i*delta;
        upperBounds[i] = min + (i + 1) * delta;
        count[i] = 0;

    }

    // find the class (part) the quartile is in
    // we keep dividing in smaller classes until we meet one of the 2 exit conditions

    while (1) {

        fclose(file_p);
        file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        // fill the frequency classes
        // during the first pass they are the initial classes, then they will be parts of the chosen part

        while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex2, &value) != EOF) {

            if (value < MEDIAN) {

                for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; i++) {

                    if (value >= lowerBounds[i] && value < upperBounds[i])
                        count[i]++;

                }

            }

        }

        // select the class containing the quartile. It will be the first one with (#elements + #elements of classes on its left) > N/2

        for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {

            tmpsum += count[i];

            if (tmpsum > limit) {

                index_quartile = i;
                break;

            }

            sum += count[i];

        }

        min = lowerBounds[index_quartile];
        max = upperBounds[index_quartile];

        // if the number of elements on the left is exactly N/2, then we are done (exit condition satisfied)
        // in that case, the quartile is calculated outside this cycle as the maximum element of the class (part) numbered index_quartile - 1

        if (sum == limit)
            break;

        // if the quartile appears many times in the set, then we need a way to figure it out before we create classes that are too small,
        // so we exit after reaching a certain fixed precision

        if (max - min < GRANULE) {

            beyondPrecision = 1;
            index_quartile++;
            break;

        }

        // set the borders of the new frequency classes (for next pass)
        // they are created by dividing the class containing the quartile

        delta = (max - min) / (CLASSES);

        for (i = 0; i < CLASSES; ++i) {

            lowerBounds[i] = min + i*delta;
            upperBounds[i] = min + (i + 1) * delta;
            count[i] = 0;

        }

        tmpsum = sum;

    }

    // now we now which class the quartile is in and we need to extract it
    // we distinguish the 2 cases of having an ever or an odd number of observations (N)

    fclose(file_p);
    file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");


    if (N % 2 || beyondPrecision) { // N is odd or the quartile value appears more than one time
        quartile = find_max(file_p, lowerBounds[index_quartile - 1], upperBounds[index_quartile - 1]);
    } else { // N is even
        double a, b;
        // a is the maximum value in the left part, where the 1st value necessary to calculate the quartile
        // b is the minimum value in the right part, where the 2nd value necessary to calculate the quartile

        a = find_max(file_p, lowerBounds[index_quartile - 1], upperBounds[index_quartile - 1]);

        fclose(file_p);
        file_p = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        b = find_min(file_p, lowerBounds[index_quartile], upperBounds[index_quartile]);

        quartile = (a + b) / 2;

    }

    fclose(file_p);

    printf("Our quartile is %f\n", quartile);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

double find_min(FILE * file_p, double lowerBound, double upperBound) {

    double value, min;
    int valueIndex;

    min = upperBound;

    while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex, &value) != EOF) {

        if (value >= lowerBound && value < upperBound && value < min)
            min = value;

    }

    return min;

}

double find_max(FILE * file_p, double lowerBound, double upperBound) {

    double value, max;
    int valueIndex;

    max = lowerBound;

    while (fscanf(file_p, "%d %lf", &valueIndex, &value) != EOF) {

        if (value >= lowerBound && value < upperBound && value > max)
            max = value;

    }

    return max;

}
```

I remember both of them working. I wrote them together with a friend less than a year ago. I forgot the logic since then (fortunately I commented it!), but now that I'm about to use it, I'd like to have it reviewed.

I'd like your opinion on this, correctness and all.

Maybe there's an elegant way to put them together?

Comment: Interesting question, but I would recommend refamiliarizing yourself with the code and reviewing it yourself first. It may be better to clean it up before asking here. You're likely to get more meaningful answers and you'll be more prepared to answer questions reviewers may have.

Comment: I reviewed it back then. It took hours to figure out and comment. I also have a couple of pages describing the method that I could post here. I'd like to hear somebody else first, though. Hint, the trickiest part was figuring out all the corner cases.

Comment: Right. You reviewed it back then. I often put code aside for a few days and come back to it after a few days to give a self review. If you give yourself an earnest review now, you may be surprised at how much better you can make it all on your own. If you take it that first step yourself, reviewers can push you even farther beyond that. But suit yourself. It was just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: You do not need to `fclose` & `fopen` the same file several times. Just do `rewind`, (Too short for an answer, hence posted as a comment.)

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks, please upvote if you found the question interesting.

Answer (score 4):

In the beginning of your code where you delcare your `find_min` and `find_max` functions, I recommend that you put the parameter names along with their type.

If your code were to be longer, it would make quickly glancing at your code easier as the code already shows at the top which argument means what in a function call.

---

To me, a function called `find_min` or `find_max` should return which of two number arguments passed is either the greatest or the least.

To better describe the functions, I recommend calling them something like `ffind_max` or `f_find_min`.

---

To be safe, you should check that the return of `fopen` is not `NULL`.

Also to be safe, you should make sure that there is even a `argv[1]` to begin with.

---

(I think) A faster and more efficient way to find out if a number is odd or even than doing `% 2` would be to `& 1`.

This will result in a 1 for an odd number and a 0 for an even number.

Here is why:

```
0111    = 7
 &
0001    = 1
```

`AND`ing with 0 will make a bit 0, but `AND`ing with 1 will return the bit being `AND`ed.

And, to enhance understanding, I would create a macro for finding out if a number is even or odd:

```
#define IS_ODD(n) n & 1
```

That way, every time you are checking if an number is odd, you don't have to write a comment about it.

---

These are just small points about your code. I'll look more into the content of your code tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. Names for the `find_` functions could be better, yes, although the parameter names do help understanding. Checking on `fopen` is a good idea. The trick for finding if a number is even is nice, maybe a just a little overkill.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the trick to be overkill at all; it's going to be easier on your processor. Think about it: by doing `%`, on a x86, the processor is going to run the `div` on either a 32 bit value and a 16 bit value, or a 64 bit value and a 32 bit value (probably the latter). The `div` instruction has a latency of 40. However, if the processor uses the `or` instruction, it will have an easier time since the `or` instruction only has a latency of 0.5 or 1.

Comment: OK, maybe this is a scenario that can benefit from the use of bitwise operators. I can use the extra speed. Other suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the benchmark / machine code when compiling with -O3 to see if gcc optimizes the `% 2` already? In my opinion it does so there is no need to use bit operations (I am not sure though)

Answer (score 3):

### Segmentation violation

I got the program to crash with following input:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 -1.0e+17
```

The problem was that the `max-min` calculation overflowed the precision of a double, and then the two buckets no longer covered the entire range.  So in the loop that counted how many numbers were in each bucket, some numbers didn't belong to any buckets.  After that, `index_median` didn't get set (it had an uninitialized value), and then `index_median` was used to index into the `lowerBounds` array.  If you want to reproduce it every time, initialize `index_median` to some large value such as `0x10000000` and then run the program on that input file.

I think one of the flaws of this algorithm is using floating point arithmetic without checking for overflows and precision loss.  There may be other unhandled corner cases other than the one I found.

Comment: Thanks. Is this more of matter of input sanitation or an actual loss of precision during calculations? What would you suggest to solve/mitigate this?

Comment: @Agostino Well to begin with, I'm not really sure why you are choosing to find the median this way instead of just using an array.  This way is going to be a lot slower.  But if you insist on not creating an array, I could think of a way that can solve the problem without requiring so many floating point operations.  Basically it would be something like a binary search for the median, similar to what you are doing but with mostly compare operations and very few add/subtract/divide operations.

Comment: Too much data to store it in memory. That's the reason. These files are huge data logs, and this is to cross-check some Apache Hadoop results. There's aren't many division operations in my code. Again, is it an input problem, or an actual loss of precision during run-time?

Comment: @Agostino It's a loss of precision during runtime.  I think to fix you should set `upperBounds[CLASSES-1] = max`.  That will fix the problem I found.  Although as I said before, I'm not sure if that is the only problem.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to add some more comments, you're welcome to do it.